# Grabbing a value from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm new to gridviews and I'm a bit confused.

My gridview has autogeneratecolumn on false and I use

```
    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

to fill the gridview.  From what I understand, I have to use a RowCreated function to pull a value?

I have to parse all the values in one column.

Comment: Which stage you try to access value? i.e. row click?

Comment: As soon as the website grabs the value from the database.  I need to convert a number into a human readable date and time and then have it in the final page.

Comment: What's the type of `reader` variable?

Comment: Do all of your parsing to the columns on the `reader` variable before assigning it to the `GridView1.DataSource`

Comment: Michael's answer might work, if you happen to be using a DataTable as your datasource. Irfan's answer is more likely to work, as it is datasource independent. You may also want to look into [Template Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ekad I'm using a iDB2DataReader.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RowDataBound Event of the Gridview.

`OnRowDataBound="RowDataboundEventHandler"` Add this to your gridview and the handler will be:

```
protect void RowDataboundEventHandler(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Get value from column directly
      string value =  e.Row.Cells[1].Text;

      // if you want to find control value
      e.Row.FindControl("controlID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `reader` is a `DataTable` and without any information about what the type of data is, you can use the below.  You'll have to provide more information or write the `yourCustomConversion()` method yourself.

```
var reader = getYourData();

foreach (DataRow row in reader.Rows)
{
    row["affectedColumn"] = yourCustomConversion(row["affectedColumn"]);
}

GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```